# Меняются все элементы массива JS

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, vue.js

Имеется таблица, генерирующаяся из двумерного массива *(array)*, состоящего из булевых значений:

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="(row, x) in array">
        <td v-for="(data, y) in row" @click="toggle(x,y)" :class="data?'active':''"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

И соответственно сама функция:

```
toggle: function(x,y) {
    this.array[x][y] = !this.array[x][y];
}
```

При нажатии на **любую ячейку** таблицы значения массива меняются у **вех ячеек**.
Это делал с использованием VUE.js, так же пробовал то же самое делать на чистом JS, однако проблема остаётся. Подскажите, в чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Вот так вот прямо NxM вызовов toggle по одному клику? То, что вы пробовали на чистом JS тут бы в виде сниппета не помешало.

Comment: Важное дополнение. Не игнорируйте :key при использовании v-for. Уровень важности [данного правила](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/index.html#%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-v-for-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE) `ESSENTIAL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я использовал такую функцию:

```
matrix: function(size) {
    return new Array(size).fill(new Array(size).fill(false));
}
```

После того, как изменил на обычный цикл:

```
matrix: function(size) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    arr.push([]);
    for(var j = 0; j< size; j++) {
      arr[i].push(false);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Всё замечательно заработало!

Comment: Можно записать например `Array.from({length: size}, () => (Array.from({length: size}, () => false)));`

Answer (score 3):

Я просто скопировал ваш код, и у меня все работает.

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      array: [
        [true, false, false, false],
        [true, true, false, true],
        [false, false, true, false]
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(x, y) {
      this.array[x][y] = !this.array[x][y];
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```css
.element {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(row, x) in array">
      <td class="element" v-for="(data, y) in row" @click="toggle(x,y)" :class="data?'active':''"/>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Интересно... Скорее всего проблема в других функциях, хотя не уверен. Я скопировал ваше и тоже заработало!